# CPP err: "called object type 'int (hashTable::*)(int, int)' is not a function or function pointer"

Tags: c++, pointers

Definition of func pointer

```
class hashTable{
    private:
        richArray<struct Slot> *slots;
        int (hashTable::* h)(int,int);
        int hLinearProbing(int,int);
. 
.
.
```

Initialisation of func pointer

```
switch (mode) {
    case 0:
        this->h = &hashTable::hLinearProbing;
        break;
    case 1:
        this->h = &hashTable::hDoubleHashing;
        break;
    case 2:
        this->h = &hashTable::hQuadHashing;
        break;
}
```

Caller

```
int hashTable::insert(int key){
    this->*h(123,11);
}
```

I am not seeing anything off. I bet its something retardedly obvious. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to call a member function by a pointer to a member function looks like this:

```
int hashTable::insert(int key){
    ( this->*h )( 123, 11 );
}
```